# 'Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function'

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I am using Jupyter to do some pratice like loss implementation, but the error about 'capture an EagerTensor' that i never see and i can figure it out. Here is the code:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import datasets

import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.testing as tm

def linear_regression():

    x = tf.random_normal([2,4])
    w = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.random_normal([4,3]))
    b = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.zeros([3]))
    y = tf.constant([2,0])

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # tape.watch([w,b])
            prob = tf.nn.softmax(x@w+b,axis=1)
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.MSE(tf.one_hot(y,depth=3),prob))
            grads = tape.gradient(loss,[w,b])
            print(sess.run(grads[0]))
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.02).minimize(loss)         
        init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)
        for i in range(150):
            sess.run(optimizer)
            print((i+1,w.eval(),b.eval(),loss.eval(),grads.eval()))
            
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    linear_regression()
```

and here is the error, and i have done some search, but still I can not fix it——Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function, and I don't even know which block leads to this:

```
/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/utils.py:15: FutureWarning: pandas.util.testing is deprecated. Use the functions in the public API at pandas.testing instead.
  import pandas.util.testing as tm
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-82aff2e0bb08> in <module>
     31 
     32 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 33     linear_regression()

<ipython-input-2-82aff2e0bb08> in linear_regression()
     17         with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
     18             # tape.watch([w,b])
---> 19             prob = tf.nn.softmax(x@w+b,axis=1)
     20             loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.MSE(tf.one_hot(y,depth=3),prob))
     21             grads = tape.gradient(loss,[w,b])

/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    901         try:
    902           y = ops.convert_to_tensor_v2(
--> 903               y, dtype_hint=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
    904         except TypeError:
    905           # If the RHS is not a tensor, it might be a tensor aware object

/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, dtype_hint, name)
   1240       name=name,
   1241       preferred_dtype=dtype_hint,
-> 1242       as_ref=False)
   1243 
   1244 

/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1283       try:
   1284         ret = conversion_func(
-> 1285             value, dtype=preferred_dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1286       except (TypeError, ValueError):
   1287         # Could not coerce the conversion to use the preferred dtype.

/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py in _dense_var_to_tensor(var, dtype, name, as_ref)
   1787 
   1788 def _dense_var_to_tensor(var, dtype=None, name=None, as_ref=False):
-> 1789   return var._dense_var_to_tensor(dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1790 
   1791 

/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py in _dense_var_to_tensor(***failed resolving arguments***)
   1212       return self.read_value().op.inputs[0]
   1213     else:
-> 1214       return self.value()
   1215 
   1216   def __iadd__(self, unused_other):

/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py in value(self)
    522     with ops.colocate_with(None, ignore_existing=True):
    523       with ops.device(self._handle.device):
--> 524         return self._read_variable_op()
    525 
    526   def _as_graph_element(self):

/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py in _read_variable_op(self)
    606     variable_accessed(self)
    607     result = gen_resource_variable_ops.read_variable_op(self._handle,
--> 608                                                         self._dtype)
    609     _maybe_set_handle_data(self._dtype, self._handle, result)
    610 

/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_resource_variable_ops.py in read_variable_op(resource, dtype, name)
    585   dtype = _execute.make_type(dtype, "dtype")
    586   _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
--> 587         "ReadVariableOp", resource=resource, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    588   _result = _op.outputs[:]
    589   _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    526                 dtype=dtype,
    527                 as_ref=input_arg.is_ref,
--> 528                 preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
    529           except TypeError as err:
    530             if dtype is None:

/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1261       graph = get_default_graph()
   1262       if not graph.building_function:
-> 1263         raise RuntimeError("Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without "
   1264                            "building a function.")
   1265       return graph.capture(value, name=name)

RuntimeError: Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function.
```

I am a rookie who just begin to learn tensorflow, so hope someone can help me, thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are writing TF version 1 style code in TF 2. I would recommend looking up some more up-to-date tutorials (e.g. on the TF website).